# how to solve $A\cap X = B$ in set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I came across a set theory problem and got stuck
here it is:

> let $P(E)$ be the set of subsets of $E$. let $A, B\in P(E)$. Consider in $P(E)$ the equation $A\cap X = B$ of unknown $X\in P(E)$
>
> a. give a necessary and sufficient condition so that this equation admits solution
>
> b. solve this equation

i think in question a) the condition is $A, B$ both are not $\phi$ (the empty set) but I am not sure, if anyone can confirm my answer

i have no idea how to solve it (question b) this is what i really need to be answered on.

forgive non-math syntax, as I am asking from my phone

Comment: $\emptyset\cap X=\emptyset$ seems quite solvable for $X\in\mathcal P(E)$, to me. The set of its solutions is $\mathcal P(E)$.

Comment: Since $A\cap X = B$, it looks like that $B$ must definitely be a subset of $A$, so $B\subseteq A$. Is it also sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A \cap X = B$ has some solution $X$, we know that $B \subseteq A$ because $A \cap X \subseteq A$ regardless of $X$.

So this is a necessary condition. So given that $B \subseteq A$ for what $X$ do we have $X \cap A = B$? $X=B$ works for sure, but also $X \cup C$ for any $C \subseteq A^\complement$. I think the set of all solutions is

$$X \in \{B \cup C: C \subseteq E\setminus A\}$$

as $X \cap A^\complement$ can be any set as long as $X \cap A$ equals $B$.

Answer (score 1):

A necessary condition is that $A$ contains $B$. This is seen directly from the fact that if $B$ has an element that $A$ does not have, no set intersected with $A$ (which reduces its 'size') gives you $B$.

To check its sufficient, simply take $X=B$.

For b), if conditions are met, again you can solve it by taking $X=B$.